# Protect an existing wagtail application

Tags: django, authentication, wagtail

I'm working on a Wagtail'based corporation intranet site. There are for now about 30,000 pages, with about 1500 users. I'm administrator of the application and the servers.

### Actual situation

I'm serving the site through Apache2 with authnz_ldap, with 3 different LDAP domains.
I'm using the REMOTE_USER auth.
All pages are marked as "public", as the auth is provided globally.

### Wanted situation

Serve the site with nginx, using django-auth-ldap as auth source (The auth module with multiple LDAP servers already works).
Remote auth will be disabled.

All users have to be connected to view the site content.

My problem is that I have to **protect** the site globally, marking **ALL** pages as private, and avoid that editors set pages as `public` accidentally.

### Questions

- How to set the entire site as `private` ?
- How to block the `public` status of pages, to force the `private` status, aka. only visible for authenticated users ?

Thanks for your help !

PS: Wagtail / Django versions are not relevant for now, as I'm migrating the application to newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Wagtail privacy settings cascade so if you mark the site root as 'private' (I recommend "accessible to logged-in users"), then the entire site will be private. Then your only issue is to keep anyone from marking it public. One option would be to remove the "Change privacy" link by overriding this template file in Wagtail 4.1: wagtailadmin/shared/side_panels/includes/status/privacy.html

https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/privacy.html#id1